# Creating a list through Flatworm

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to load attribute with string values read through flatfile.

```
private List<String> attribute = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I created

```
public List<String> getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(List<String> attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public void addAttribute(String atr)
       {
        attribute.add(atr);
       }
```

Lets say my input record is :

```
NHJames   Elliot   4183306636 4189965965 4182235656
```

I was wanting to load those last 3 phone numbers in that attribute list. It can be 11 legth long but can be of multiple size.

I tried in my xml as :

```
<record-element length="11" addMethod="addAttribute" beanref="personInput.attribute" minCount="1" maxCount="99" type="char">
</record-element>
```

I am getting  `argument type mismatch error`.

I am following http://flatworm.sourceforge.net/
Is it even doable. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your error lies in `beanref="personInput.attribute"`:

```
<record-element length="11" addMethod="addAttribute" beanref="personInput.attribute" minCount="1" maxCount="99" type="char">
</record-element>
```

Instead replace `beanref="personInput.attribute"` with `beanref="personInput"` to become:

```
<record-element length="11" addMethod="addAttribute" beanref="personInput" minCount="1" maxCount="99" type="char">
</record-element>
```

Comment: :) thanks for pointing out the mistake... now I am getting java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. Does my xml needs tweaking little bit to reapeat or something...